# MySql all rows with sum of one column

Tags: php, mysql

I try to create a query to select all rows in a table with sum of one column name newtotal

This is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_activities
       ,(SELECT SUM(db_newtotal) as total FROM tbl_activities)  {$sql}
```

{$sql} is where column_name=input from a seach form

But I have this error:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

I try to do that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_activities
     ,(SELECT SUM(db_newtotal) as total FROM tbl_activities) as Table {$sql}
```

But I have this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Table where db_projectname='Barbara Bui'' at line 1

I print the query and this is the output

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_activities
     ,(SELECT SUM(db_newtotal) as total FROM tbl_activities) as Table 
where db_projectname='Barbara Bui'
```

The output I want should be like this: ll record with projectname name ='Barbara Bui' with the sum the newtotal

```
projectname   location    Cost
Barbara Bui   verdun      100
Barbara Bui   kaslik      200 
Barbara Bui   achrafieh   500
Total                     800
```

**Query**

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_activities
        union all
        select db_id,db_category,db_subcategory,db_taskname,db_predecessors,db_unit,db_qty,db_wo,db_duration,db_startdate,db_enddate,db_asd,db_add,db_transferredto,db_prb,db_anotes,db_aduration,db_projectname,db_A,db_AA,db_AAA,db_cost,db_status,db_room,db_floor,db_date,sum(db_newtotal) as total from tbl_activities
       {$sql}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is because `table` is a reserved keyword.

You want to use `UNION ALL` like this:

```
select projectname, location, cost
from tbl_activities {$sql}

union all

select 'Total', null, sum(cost)
from tbl_activities {$sql};
```

Using the parameter to apply the where clause, it becomes:

```
select projectname,
    location,
    cost
from tbl_activities {$sql}

union all

select 'Total',
    null,
    sum(cost)
from tbl_activities {$sql}
```

If you have more columns in your first part of the UNION ALL, then make sure to all those many nulls in the second select.

```
select db_id, db_category, db_subcategory, db_taskname, db_predecessors, db_unit, db_qty, db_wo, db_duration, db_startdate, db_enddate, db_asd, db_add, db_transferredto, db_prb, db_anotes, db_aduration, db_projectname, db_A, db_AA, db_AAA, db_cost, db_status, db_room, db_floor, db_date, db_newtotal
from tbl_activities {$sql}

union all

select null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, sum(db_newtotal)
from tbl_activities {$sql}
```

Comment: can you please check above the update of the query it's give me this error  The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: @Developer - Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Table is a reserved word in most RDMS so you cannot use it as an alias, try to change to

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_activities,(SELECT SUM(db_newtotal) as total FROM tbl_activities) as myTable {$sql}
```

and see if that works

Comment: your query give me the rows i want but the sum it's not correct